# Filter array of objects with another array of objects and add extra key to matching objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following two arrays, I want to get second array, but matching objects should contain one more extra key **"select" : true,** and not matching objects should contain **"select" : false.**

```
var firstArray = [{id: -1, type: "group"},
                  {id: -2, type: "group"}];

var secondArray = [{id: -3, type: "group"},
                   {id: -2, type: "group"},
                   {id: -1, type: "group"}];
```

**Expected outcome:**

```
var expectedArray = [{id: -1, type: "group", select: true},
                     {id: -2, type: "group", select: true},
                     {id: -3, type: "group", select: false}];
```

**I have tried below code:**

```
for(var i=0;i<firstArray.length;i++){
             for(var j=0;j<secondArray.length;j++){
               console.log(firstArray[i].id,secondArray[j].id)
               if(firstArray[i].id===secondArray[j].id){
                 if(secondArray[j].hasOwnProperty('select')){
                   secondArray[j].select=true;
                   // console.log('true select property',secondArray[j].select)
                 }
                 else{
                   secondArray[j].select=true;
                   // console.log('true adding new',secondArray[j].select)
                 }
               }else{
                  secondArray[j]['select']=false;
                 // console.log('false not match',secondArray[j].select)
               }
             }
          }
```

Comment: @user11299053, Sure, It works, Please upvote to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with just one line of code:

```js
var firstArray = [
 {id: -1, type: "group"}, 
 {id: -2, type: "group"}
];

var secondArray = [
 {id: -3, type: "group"}, 
 {id: -2, type: "group"}, 
 {id: -1, type: "group"}
];

const result = secondArray.map(item => ({...item, 'select': firstArray.some(entry => entry.id == item.id)}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
}

.as-console-row {
  background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of all the ids which are present in `firstArray`. Then loop through the `secondArray` using `forEach` and add `select` value based on whether the set [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) the id

```js
let firstArray=[{id:-1,type:"group"},{id:-2,type:"group"}],
    secondArray=[{id:-3,type:"group"},{id:-2,type:"group"},{id:-1,type:"group"}];

const ids = new Set(firstArray.map(a => a.id));
secondArray.forEach(a => a.select = ids.has(a.id))

console.log(secondArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
var ans = secondArray.map(s=> {
var match = firstArray.find(f=> f.id === s.id);
if(match) s['select'] = true;
else s['select'] = false;
return s;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the `secondArray`, it is better to not modify it directly. We can use immutable way by creating another array that has `select` property. For this case, we will use `map`.

```js
var firstArray = [{id: -1, type: "group"},
                  {id: -2, type: "group"}];

var secondArray = [{id: -3, type: "group"},
                   {id: -2, type: "group"},
                   {id: -1, type: "group"}];

const expectedArray = secondArray.map(item => {
  const idExist = firstArray.find(itemInFirst => itemInFirst.id === item.id);
  return {
    ...item,
    select: idExist !== undefined
  }
});

console.log(expectedArray);
```